# Update a value for all the duplicate rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have 4 columns

```
FirstName | LastName | Address | Vote
```

There are few rows that have the same firstname, lastname and address and has vote of 1 for the first duplicate row

For Example:

```
FirstName | LastName | Address     | Vote
John      | Doe      | 10 drive st | 1
John      | Doe      | 10 drive st | 0
Bob       | Smith    | 15 lexar dr | 0
Bob       | Smith    | 15 lexar dr | 0
```

I want to be able to update the duplicate's Vote values if the first instance is 1. From the example, I want the John's duplicate vote to be updated to 1 as well.

Query I have tried so far is: `SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, ADDRESS HAVING Count(*) > 1 WHERE Vote = 1`

How can I incorporate the UPDATE query, so that it only updates the duplicate Vote column if the first instance is Vote = 1

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "the first instance".  SQL tables represent unordered sets, so without a column specifying the ordering, there is no meaning to "first".

That said, you can set the non-1 values to 1 for a given name/address combo by doing:

```
update table t
     set vote = 1
     where vote <> 1 and
           exists (select 1
                   from table t2
                   where t2.firstname = t.firstname and
                         t2.lastname = t.lastname and
                         t2.address = t.address and
                         t2.vote = 1
                  );
```

This is ANSI standard syntax and should work in most databases.